# Python hanging at continue when trying to read data from dataframe

Tags: python

I'm iterating through a DataFrame of file locations. If I find a file that I want then I try to unzip it and then try to rename it. If that fails then I want to continue to the next row of the dataframe. The problem is that if I call "continue" then instead of jumping back to the main for loop it jumps back to the previous for loop and then my program hangs. Is there any way to specify which for loop to fall back to in case of an error?

Here is my psuedo code:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows(): #if something fails I want to go back here
    #get the file location       
    for file in location: #"continue" is taking me back to here which I don't want
        #search for file
        if file found:
            file_found = True
    if not file_found:
        continue
    else:
        file_found = False
    try:
        #unzip file
    except:
        #could not unzip
        continue
    try:
        #rename unzipped file
    except:
        try:
            #try renaming a different way
        except:
            #could not rename file
            continue
```

Comment: How about a `break` statement? From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops): "The break statement, like in C, breaks out of the innermost enclosing for or while loop."

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I run in to the same problem there in that python executes at the previous instead of outer for loop.

Comment: Hm, ok I'll try to reproduce your results using your code

Comment: Maybe you have some indentation wrong... did you check that?

Comment: Sorry guys, it seems that there was another error in my code that was not shown in my pseudo code. Sorry for wasting your time. I'll be more careful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest fix is to use [`break`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops), which exits its enclosing loop.